# hapi-swagger returning JSON data but no UI

Tags: node.js, api, swagger, hapi-swagger

My routes contain the the 'api' tag

```
... 
{
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/blah/albums',
  options: { tags: ['api'], handler: myHandlerFunction }
},
...
```

and I am including the Inert, Vision, and hapi-swagger plugins

```
import Hapi from '@hapi/hapi'
import Inert from '@hapi/inert'
import Vision from '@hapi/vision'
import HapiSwagger from 'hapi-swagger'
...
  const plugins = [
    Inert,
    Vision,
    {
      plugin: HapiSwagger,
      options: swaggerOptions
    },
...
```

When I hit the `/swagger.json` endpoint I get the correct JSON data, but when I hit the `/documentation` endpoint like the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-swagger#tagging-your-api-routes) says I get a `{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}`